# How can I make Delphi 2009 open my application in the second monitor by default?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, multiple-monitors

When debugging I always want Delphi to open my application in the second monitor but it always open in the first one, I know I can save the application placement before closing but I want it to always open in the second monitor when in debug mode.

Is there some way to configure delphi 2009 to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Delphi doesn't have his feature.

What I do is to add code to the OnCreate handler of the main form that moves the form to the second monitor if the Delphi-Debugger is attached to the application.

```
  if (DebugHook <> 0) and (Screen.MonitorCount > 1) then
    Left := Screen.Monitors[1].Left;
```